# Not found nagios index page

Tags: php, apache, nagios

I have installed Nagios on server following manual: http://linuxcalling.blogspot.com/2016/07/installing-nagios-core-without-root.html

but after running it page is not found:

`Not Found
The requested URL /nagios/index.php was not found on this server.`

Error in logs show:

`[Wed Oct 10 14:48:15.520899 2018] [:error] [pid 2085:tid 139654527371008] [client 10.247.250.104:52692] script '/var/opt/user/monitoring/nagios/shareindex.php' not found or unable to stat`

but location to index page is on location and '/' is missing:

`/var/opt/user/monitoring/nagios/share/index.php`

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

so it was solved by making following config change 'conf/nagios.conf':

```
...
Alias /nagios/ "/var/opt/user/monitoring/nagios/share/./"

<Directory "/var/opt/user/monitoring/nagios/share/./">
...
```